# node.JS - express - connect-redis how to delete a record

Tags: node.js

I have here is an example directly got from express document.

```
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({ secret: "keyboard cat" }));
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis');
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({ secret: "keyboard cat", store: new RedisStore }));
```

What I know is, this code will create a session id, and automatically store the session id in redis databse. Right?

Now, let's say the generated session_id was 555444, how can I delete the record when it's no longer needed ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do any of these work?

```
store.destroy('555444', function(err) { ... })
```

or

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    if (req.session.sid == '555444') {
        req.session.destroy(function(err) { ... });
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar situation where I wanted to destroy existing session and clear cookie during logout. This seems to work fine for me (store is an instance of RedisStore).

```
app.get('/logout', function (req, res) {
  res.contentType('json');
  store.destroy(req.sessionID, function () {
    req.session.destroy(function () {
      res.clearCookie(sessionOpts.key, { path: '/' });
      res.send({ success: true });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: what is store here? is store = require('connect-redis')(session);

Answer (score 0):

Each session key set with expires on redis, so those will expires automatically after some time (as per session maxAge). [Express session](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#session-support)

Answer (score 0):

I created an example on Github that uses [backbone.js](/questions/tagged/backbone.js), [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js), [express.js](/questions/tagged/express.js), [mongodb](/questions/tagged/mongodb), [socket.io](/questions/tagged/socket.io) and [redis](/questions/tagged/redis) if you want to check it out.  I contributed it to the backbone-boilerplates repo.

[Fork it here on Github](https://github.com/addyosmani/backbone-boilerplates/tree/master/option7_node_socketio)

- socket.io for real-time multi-user editing
- mongodb for storing the data
- redis for managing sessions
- redis pub/sub for record locks so two users don't try to edit the same Todo

Answer (score 0):

You just need to provide the sessionID to the destroy method, this will clear out that session key from the Redis database. Here's the code that worked for me:

```
req.session.destroy(req.sessionID, function () {
    // Passport logout
    req.logout();
});
```